# Define `\widebar` command in matplotlib when using LaTeX rendering

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

When using matplotlib default's math rendering, you get the command `$\widebar{A}$` "built-in":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2])
plt.gca().set_ylabel(r"$\widebar{A}$")
```

and all is good.

However, if, for some reason, you need to activate LaTeX rendering (in my case, because I have to use Palatino as the math font), you lose the built-in ability to draw a wide bar on letters. LaTeX' $\overline$ would be a solution, but it's not optimal (see [this question on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16337/95896)). The best option would be Hendrik Vogt's definition, given as an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/95896) to that same question. However, it seems quite tricky to add it to the preamble in matplotlib. I first tried to set it through my own `.mplstyle` without success. I inserted it as a one-liner, but still, I think, the `#` characters were interpreted as comments. So I thought to set it directly at runtime through:

```
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath} \makeatletter \let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent \newcommand
     *\if@single[3]{%   \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%   \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^
     H$}%   \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi   } \newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna} \newcommand*\wid
     ebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}} \newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar
     @{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}} \newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%   \begingroup   \def\mathaccent##1##2{%     
     \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent     \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi     \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\
     macc@nucleus}_{}$}%     \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%     \dimen@\wd\tw@     \advance\d
     imen@-\wd\z@     \divide\dimen@ 3     \@tempdima\wd\tw@     \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace     \divide\@tempd
     ima 10     \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima     \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi     \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@     
     \if#31       \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%       \advance\dim
     en@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna       \let\final@kern#2%       \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi       \if\final
     @kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi     \else       \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%     \fi   }%   \macc@depth\@
     ne   \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar   \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgrou
     p\macc@group\relax}%   \macc@set@skewchar\relax   \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a   \if#31     \macc@nested@a\r
     elax111{#1}%   \else     \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%     \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#
     1\endmarker     \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else       \def\first@char{}%     \fi     \macc@nested@a\relax111
     {\first@char}%   \fi   \endgroup } \makeatother')
```

With no surprise, it didn't work.

Here's LaTeX' report:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../d49352dbf7e233191e06411a7bb3d1ee.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/cm-super/type1ec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
Runaway argument?
{\makeatletter \@ifpackageloaded {underscore}{}{\usepackage [strings]\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ../d49352dbf7e233191e06411a7bb3d1ee.tex
                                           
No pages of output.
```

Is there actually a way to define more complicated preambles than `\usepackage{...}` in matplotlib, e.g. by linking an external file containing it? Or is there a better way to get a well-working wide bar in latex mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying again, I realized I stupidly forgot to remove the LaTeX comments and all percent characters at the end of the lines.

So this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath} \makeatletter \let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent \newcommand*\if@single[3]{   \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}   \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}   \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi   } \newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna} \newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}} \newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}} \newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{   \begingroup   \def\mathaccent##1##2{     \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent     \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi     \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}     \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}     \dimen@\wd\tw@     \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@     \divide\dimen@ 3     \@tempdima\wd\tw@     \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace     \divide\@tempdima 10     \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima     \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi     \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@     \if#31       \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}       \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna       \let\final@kern#2       \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi       \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi     \else       \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}     \fi   }   \macc@depth\@ne   \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar   \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}   \macc@set@skewchar\relax   \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a   \if#31     \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}   \else     \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}     \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker     \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else       \def\first@char{}     \fi     \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}   \fi   \endgroup } \makeatother'

plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=preamble)
```

actually works.

Unfortunately, it does not work in the `.mplstyle`, so I'll let this question open to see if anyone has a better solution.